# Gridx/Grid DOJO : issue with checkbox and filter : when filter is used, checkboxes get uncheked

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox, dojo, gridx

I am using gridx/grid to make grid where for checkboxes, "IndirectSelect and ExtendedSelect" are used. The issue is, when I select some checkboxes and then type something in filter, all checked checkboxes become unchecked.

Is there a way the checkboxes checked state can be maintained when filter is used?

Please help. Thanks in Advance.

Following is the code to create grid:

```
this.grid=new Grid({
  id: 'grid',
  cacheClass: Cache,
  store: this.store,
  structure: this.layout,
  vScrollerBuffSize: 300,
  selectRowTriggerOnCell: true,
  barTop: [
    DropDownPager,
    { pluginClass: QuickFilter, style: 'text-align: right;' }
  ],
  barBottom: [
    LinkSizer,
    { pluginClass: Summary, style:'text-align:center' },
    { pluginClass: LinkPager, style: 'text-align: right;' }
  ],
  modules: [
    extendedSelect,
    RowHeader,
    IndirectSelect,
    CellWidget,
    ColumnResizer,
    Bar,
    VirtualVScroller,
    { moduleClass: Pagination, initialPageSize:10 },
    Filter,
    FilterBar
  ],
  autoHeight: false
}, document.createElement('div'));
```